# When using Report Viewer and asked for datasource my data access class does not show up

Tags: c#, asp.net, report-viewer2010

I am new to using the report viewer control.

The way I am currently creating a report is by calling a stored procedure and inserting input parameters to query a table in a database and to return a list of rows.

The rows are inserted into a Data Table and the Data Table is returned.

The data table is binded to a gridview which the user can view.

Now my problem....

I would like to use the report viewer to display the data instead of the gridview so the users can easily export the data and view a nice graph with it.

The Stored Procedure is called from my data access class which is just a class I have in my project (it is not in a folder).

When I go to create a report viewer and get asked for my datasource my data access class does not show up.  How can I get the results (the returned data table) from my stored procedure function to get inserted into the report viewer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing to get the report viewer to access my datatable was add a dataset to my project.  Within that dataset I had to create a datatable with the same column names as in my code generated data table. From there I went to my report and added a table and pointed it towards the datatable which was created within the dataset.  Then in my code I programmatically added the datatable using the code described above from Shelby.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the programmatic approach,

```
//Load Report Definition.
// From File.
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = "C:\\Report.rdlc";
//Load Report Data.
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", data));
//Refresh Control.
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
```

If you have a DataTable with your data in it, you simply Add it to the ReportViewer as a DataSource. "DataSet1" is the name of the dataset in the report currently loaded into the report viewer.

So if you were using Entity Framework it would be like this.

```
//Create Connection.
Entities db = new Entities();

//Get the Data Using the query supplied (Where Entities.SomeObject is the Entity to retrieve data).
IQueryable<Object> data = db.CreateQuery<Object>("SELECT VALUE c FROM Entities.SomeObject AS c WHERE c.SomeValue> 0");

//Reset Control. Doesn't Usually work if this is skipped for some reason.
ReportViewer1.Reset();
//Load Report Definition.
// From File.
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = "C:\\Report.rdlc";
//Load Report Data.
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", data));
//Refresh Control.
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
```

Same should work for a DataTable.

Comment: Ok I see what your doing by programmatically setting the data source, but what are you doing where you set the report path to a location in the C drive?

Comment: That's where my Report file is located (.rdlc) so you could do `ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("~/Reports/Report1.rdlc");` to load a report that's in a Reports Folder directly in your project.

I have it set that way for simplicity because I have multiple projects and I use the same reports to test all of them so instead of having multiple copies of them I just have them saved to C drive.

Comment: So not only do I need to programtically set the datasource, I must also have a report already created in a folder and point ReportViewer1 to it.  Can my report be blank and will it know how to handle the data source? Or must I also programtically create some container like a gridview in the report and point it to the data source as well.

Comment: ReportViewer is just a control that displays reports. The Report is the structure in which your data is displayed (this is saved as an .rdlc file) and the datasource is the data that is supplied to your report.
So the ReportViewer displays the DataSource's data using the structure provided by the report's definition (.rdlc). If that makes it any clearer.